# VS C# - Microsoft Excel Object library reference

Tags: c#

EDIT:

I am trying to use Microsoft Excel in Visual Studio C#.

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace write_data_to_excel
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();

            Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
            Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
            object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

            xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
            xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

            xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1] = "ID";
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 2] = "Name";
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 1] = "1";
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[3, 1] = "2";
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[3, 2] = "Two";

            xlWorkBook.SaveAs("C:\\examplewrite.xlsx", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
            xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
            xlApp.Quit();


        }
    }
}
```

Error:

**System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Cannot access 'examplewrite.xlsx'.'**

I am using VS Community 2017.

Comment: You cannot write to the C:\ directory unless your program runs with UAC elevation.  Pick a better directory, the user's Documents folder would be a logical choice.  Environment.GetFolderPath() to get its path.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, it requires that all client machines have the same version of Microsoft Excel installed unfortunately.

more info found here: https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/spreadsheet/articles/c-sharp-microsoft-office-interop-excel-automation

Comment: I have solved that. Now I am getting the second error. Please look at that.

Comment: SOLVED EVERYTHING.